# How to connect to multiple IBM queue connections having different QM, Host, Port from Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I want to clear data from single queue which is hosted in 3 different queue managers with different host and port. Is there anyway to configure with single jmsTemplate that connects to 3 Queue managers using mqQueueConnectionFactory? Can anyone help on this as I am unable to get examples

Currently using ibm-mq-allclient:9.1.3 library

Comment: Are you looking for the CONNECTIONNAMELIST ? See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=reconnection-using-automatic-jms-client

Comment: ConnectionNameList is only for multiple host and port configuration with same QueueManager but in my case each queuemanager having different host/port

Comment: Ah sorry, when you said single queue I thought that you meant there was one queue and it could be hosted on one of three places. So I think you have three queues then? One on each queue manager?

Comment: i am having one only queue only but it was hosted on 3 different queue managers 

QueueName: xyz
QueueManager: QM

xyz -> QM1, Host1, Port1
xyz -> QM2, Host2, Port2
xyz -> QM3, Host3, Port3

This is how my queue is hosted on 3 different Queue managers

Comment: Then you have three queues I'm afraid to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 3 different Queue Connection Factories (QCF) and run the program with each different QCF.

Why reinvent the wheel when there are many freely available open-source programs that already do that?

Comment: yes we can create 3 different connection factories but identifying if there is any approach to have into single connection factory such that we can use same jmsTemplate and when I want to do some data operations like clear queue, read queue it will be easy.

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is, how would it be possible to share a QCF when pretty much every value will be different? i.e. different queue manager name, different hostname, different port #, different channel name. The M in MQ does not stand for magic. You need to create 3 QCFs so your application can connect to the 3 different queue managers.